# Google Spreadsheet API - Accessing a spreadsheet created with service account

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I created a service provider in my laravel app which connects with the google spreadsheet API, and I am able to create new spreadsheets, edit existing ones (with the right sharing permissions of course) and so on.

The problem is that I supplied my service account's json credentials key, hence the spreadsheets that are being created are owned by this cryptic mail address, so after the creation - I get an ID and when I'm trying to access the spreadsheet it gives me this 'request access' page, and when i'm trying to request access to my own email (I defined myself as an 'owner' of the project as well), I get these delivery status notifications via mail -

> Your message wasn't delivered to
>   xxxxxx@yyyyyy-1x3x71x4x27x4.iam.gserviceaccount.com because the domain
>   admanager-1x3x71x4x27x4.iam.gserviceaccount.com couldn't be found.
>   Check for typos or unnecessary spaces and try again.

Obviously it's trying to send an email from me (`xxxx@gmail.com`) to my service account email, to request an access to this specific spreadsheet, and of course this address doesn't really exist. I feel like I'm doing something wrong from the very first place..

**GoogleServiceProvider.php -**

```
class GoogleServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

/**
 * Register services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{

    $this->app->singleton('google_spreadsheet_client', function ($app) {
        // we will instantiate the Google Spread Sheet Client once in this function
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName('xxxxx');
        $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS);
        $client->setAuthConfig('xxxxxx-1xyxyxyxyxyxy-221ca2fc3123.json');
        $google_service_sheets = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
        return $google_service_sheets;
    });
}
```

**SpreadsheetController.php**

```
class SpreadsheetsController extends Controller {

public function create() {
    $service = resolve('google_spreadsheet_client');
    $spreadsheet = new \Google_Service_Sheets_Spreadsheet([
        'properties' => [
            'title' => 'test'
        ]
    ]);
    $spreadsheet = $service->spreadsheets->create($spreadsheet, [
        'fields' => 'spreadsheetId'
    ]);
    printf("Spreadsheet ID: %s\n", $spreadsheet->spreadsheetId);
   }
}
```

And as I said - I do get a response with a string that looks like an actual spreadsheet ID, but can't access it with my own email for some reason..

Comment: has your Service Account created a Permission to your User Account for the new spreadsheet?

Comment: not sure about it.. can you elaborate please?

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't. see https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions

Comment: @GonrasKarols How are you going with your Google scripts problem? Worked it out, or still needing help?